# ItextSharp - Acrofields are empty

Tags: itext

I have a PDF form with filled out fields. If I try to read the acrofields they are empty. But in the PDF I can change the values and save them.

```
private static string GetFormFieldNamesWithValues(PdfReader pdfReader)
{
    return string.Join("\r\n", pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields
                                   .Select(x => x.Key + "=" +
                                    pdfReader.AcroFields.GetField(x.Key))
                                   .ToArray());
}

var reader = new PdfReader((DataContext as PDFContext).Datei);
AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
txt.Text = GetFormFieldNamesWithValues(reader);
```

How to read the fields?

Comment: Your code works on my sample PDF, can you provide the PDF that doesn't work? Also, can you check if the PDF form is using XFA by inspecting this property `form.Xfa.XfaPresent`

Comment: With my pdf the xfapresent is false. But in another PDF where i can read the fields it is also false. How can I add the pdf?

Comment: SO doesn't allow uploading of files, see this http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4637

Comment: ok...here is the link: [PDF](http://www.unirent.de/down/ll_formular.pdf) . Hope you can help me to find out why the fields are not readable. If they are not readable by itext maybe you know another component. ty

Comment: If it helps the PDF was created with wpcubed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly your PDF is broken. The fields are defined as *widget annotations* on the page level, but they aren't referenced in the `/AcroForm` fields set on the *document root level*.

You can fix your PDF using the [FixBrokenForm](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=236) code sample:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfDictionary root = reader.getCatalog();
PdfDictionary form = root.getAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
PdfArray fields = form.getAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);

PdfDictionary page;
PdfArray annots;
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    page = reader.getPageN(i);
    annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    for (int j = 0; j < annots.size(); j++) {
        fields.add(annots.getAsIndirectObject(j));
    }
}
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

You should inform the creators of the tool that was used to produce the form that their PDFs aren't compliant with the PDF reference.

Comment: Thank you, Lowagie; after Fixing the PDF, I can read the form values. I will inform the tool developer.

Comment: When I run this code, it says annots is null. How can i come over it?

Comment: @hiule An interactive form without annots is an XFA Form. XFA stands for the XML Forms Architecture. It's totally different from the AcroForm technology that used widget annotations for the visual representation of fields. Please be aware that you won't get much feedback if you comment on a post dating from more than 4 years ago.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I understand it now. It made me confuse because of 
"pdfStamper.AcroFields.Xfa". I thought it's a part of AcroForm. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is my c#-Code:

```
   PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
        PdfDictionary form = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
        PdfArray fields = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);

        PdfDictionary page;
        PdfArray annots;
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            page = reader.GetPageN(i);
            annots = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            for (int j = 0; j < annots.Size; j++)
            {
                fields.Add(annots.GetAsIndirectObject(j));
            }
        }
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

C# version

```
    public void FixBrokenForm(string src, string dest)
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
        PdfDictionary form = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
        PdfArray fields = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);

        PdfDictionary page;
        PdfArray annots;
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            page = reader.GetPageN(i);
            annots = page.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
            for (int j = 0; j < annots.Size; j++)
            {
                fields.Add(annots.GetAsIndirectObject(j));
            }
        }
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
      }
```

You will need [Itextsharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp) to make the above code work.

Answer (score 0):

The answers  with the FixBrokenForm code are good, but don't forget to call fields.setGenerateAppearances(true) or you'll lose the fields if you call stamper.setFormFlattening(true).
You can do like this:

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create));
// Add these 2 lines ***************************
AcroFields acrofields = stamper.getAcroFields();
acrofields.setGenerateAppearances(true);
// *********************************************
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
```