# iTextSharp filed names display doesn't work

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-form

I have a sample C# code that I actually took it from an article to explain how to list field names from PDF file. The code was taken from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fill-in-pdf-form-fields-using-the-open-source-itextsharp-dll/)

Before I took the code, I have added the following DLLs to my project's reference:

- itextsharp.dll
- itextsharp.pdfa.dll
- itextsharp.xmlworker.dll
- itextsharp.xtra.dll

Then I created one simple form with one TextBox and I set multiline property to **True** for the TextBox

On form load, I called a method `ListFieldNames()` to list the fields into the TextBox according to the article.

Below is the code:

```
private void ListFieldNames()
    {
        string pdfTemplate = "C:\\Users\\aalsahli\\Desktop\\I-9Form.pdf";
        this.Text += " - " + pdfTemplate;

        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var de in pdfReader.AcroFields.Fields)
        {
            sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
        textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;
    }
```

When I run the application, nothing displayed to the TextBox and I didn't get any error message.

When I tried to debug the application, I found out that the code never get in the for loop at all which means the line `sb.Append(de.Key.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);` was never executed

Here is the Output that I get when I run the application:

```
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\aalsahli\source\repos\ReadPDF\ReadPDF\bin\Debug\ReadPDF.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'ReadPDF.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: ReadPDF.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\aalsahli\source\repos\ReadPDF\ReadPDF\bin\Debug\itextsharp.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

Comment: How many AcroFields.Fields do you have? Print/verify it before foreach loop

Comment: @Mate, the count is 0, this is interesting! But the file location is correct.

Comment: I can't tell you with any confidence why the field count is zero, but perhaps looking at this similar question (and answer) might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909979/itextsharp-acrofields-are-empty

Comment: Yes, but PDF files've always been a headache. You need to check how the fields were created and how itextsharp recognizes them. My recomendation is: patience

Comment: You could add itextsharp via nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/

Comment: @Mate, yes, I did already with no luck

Comment: The issue is definitely caused by the file, I have tested another PDF form and it worked nicely. I don't know if there is anything can be done to the file though!

Comment: Exact. You can try with more files and some won't work. Ideally, they should always be generated in the same way. Elgonzo's comment talks about how to repair it.  It's in java, but you can follow https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-13#491-fixbrokenform.java

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: If the form is an XFA form, the number of AcroForm fields can be zero too. In that case, there are no AcroForm fields, only fields defined in XML using the XML Forms Architecture.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, this is a very good hint

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, the file is the I-9 form from: [US gov](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/i-9.pdf?download=1). Do you think it will work? If not, is there a way to fix this and make it work?

Comment: Read the FAQ: https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-dynamic-xfa (version 5 answer) or https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/interactive-forms/itext7-how-fill-out-pdf-file-programmatically-dynamic-xfa (iText 7 answer; preferred). As for finding out the structure of the XML data: ask the US government or extract and interprete the data definition.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, thanks